# ASP.NET MVC 5, How to get raw JSON/request-body-content when JSON is invalid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following code to get raw JSON in my action method

```
 var stream = new MemoryStream();

 var context = (HttpContextBase)request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"];
 if (context.Request.InputStream != null)
 {
     context.Request.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
     context.Request.InputStream.CopyTo(stream);
 }
```

It works perfectly as long as JSON is valid and bound to my model. Until I send an invalid JSON like the following

```
{
  "firstName" : "John",
  "lastName" : "Doe",
  "address" : {
    street" : "123 Hey Where is the opening quote parkway",
    "city" : "Boston",
    "state" : "MA",
    "zip" : 03051
    }
}
```

In that case the following line fails

```
if (context.Request.InputStream != null)
```

Precisely, getter of InputStream property throws an `InvalidOperationException`.

I investigated further under debugger and found out that there is an alternate stream that is not throwing exception, showing length of my stream as 201 bytes (which matches with what's above) and it has data. So I decided to read that instead.

```
var stream = new MemoryStream();
var task = request.Content.CopyToAsync(stream);
task.Wait();
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

The above code did give me the raw JSON but it started copying that into my stream not from the beginning, but from the point where I am missing the opening quote. so I only got the following part.

```
street" : "123 Hey Where is the opening quote parkway",
    "city" : "Boston",
    "state" : "MA",
    "zip" : 03051
    }
}
```

So it turns out, this is the stream that the binder actually used and abandoned where it could not parse so the position is set at byte # 72. Now I could use `Seek` method and rewind it, but request.Content is not really of type `Stream` and there is no public property that exposes that stream that I can rewind.

How do I get the raw JSON in my action method regardless of whether my JSON is a valid JSON or not?

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling with context in the debugger, I found a stream that would work in case of an invalid JSON. I am not too happy to have done it this way, but until someone posts a better answer, the following worked for me.

```
Stream stream = null;
try
{
    var context = (HttpContextBase)request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"];
    // The following getter call throws an exception, hence the try-block hack
    stream = context.Request.InputStream;
}
catch (System.Exception)
{
    var context = (OwinContext)request.Properties["MS_OwinContext"];

    stream = context.Request.Body;
}
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
var myJson = new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd();
```